# Highlight a part of an extjs4 line chart

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4

In the extjs 4.1.1a code below is a working example of a line chart. Now I need to highlight a part of that chart on a given min and max timestamp.

```
{'xtype' : 'chart',
'store' : 'ChartData',
'height' : '100%',
'width' : '100%',
'legend' : {'position' : top},
'axes': [{
    'title': 'Power',
    'type': 'Numeric',
    'position': 'left',
    'fields': ['power']
},{
    'title': 'Timestamp',
    'type': 'Numeric',
    'position': 'bottom',
    'fields': ['timestamp'],
    'minorTickSteps': 3
}],
'series': [{
    'type': 'line',
    'fill': true,
    'axis' : 'left',
    'xField': 'timestamp',
    'yField': 'power'
}]}
```

I've searched the sencha forum and found nothing in particular that meets my requirements.
For now I managed to change the color of the points on the line chart with a custom renderer.

```
'renderer': function(sprite, record, attr, index, store) {
var item = store.getAt(index);
if(item != undefined && (item.get('timestamp') < startdate || item.get('timestamp') > enddate)){
    return Ext.apply(attr, {'fill': '#00cc00', 'stroke-width': 3, 'radius': 4});
}else{
    return Ext.apply(attr, {'fill': '#ff0000', 'stroke-width': 3, 'radius': 4});
}}
```

But I have not found a way to change the color below the line.
Any suggestions on that?

**UPDATE - Working fine now**

I  implement a solution based on the answer given by Colombo.

```
doCustomDrawing: function () {: function (p){
var me = this, chart = me.chart;
if(chart.rendered){
    var series = chart.series.items[0];
    if (me.groupChain != null) {
        me.groupChain.destroy();
        me.groupChain = null;
    }
    me.groupChain = Ext.create('Ext.draw.CompositeSprite', {
        surface: chart.surface
    });
    if(series != null && series.items != null){
        var surface = chart.surface;
        var pathV = 'M';
        var first = true;
        // need first and last x cooridnate
        var mX = 0,hX = 0;
        Ext.each(series.items, function(item){
            var storeItem = item.storeItem,
                    pointX = item.point[0],
                    pointY = item.point[1];
            // based on given startdate and enddate start collection path coordinates
            if(!(storeItem.get('timestamp') < startdate || storeItem.get('timestamp') > enddate)){
                if(hX<pointX){
                    hX = pointX;
                }
                if(first){
                    first = false;
                    mX = pointX;
                    pathV+= + pointX + ' ' + pointY;
                }else{
                    pathV+= ' L' + pointX + ' ' + pointY;
                }
            }
        });
        var sprite = Ext.create('Ext.draw.Sprite', {
            type: 'path',
            fill: '#f00',
            surface: surface,
            // to draw a sprite with the area below the line we need the y coordinate of the x axe which is in my case items[1]
            path : pathV + ' L'+ hX + ' ' + chart.axes.items[1].y + ' L'+ mX + ' ' + chart.axes.items[1].y + 'z'
        });
        me.groupChain.add(sprite);
        me.groupChain.show(true);
    }
}}
```

This looks really good and has the effect I was hoping for **and** in case you resize the container the new sprite **is** cleared from the chart. Thx to Colombo again.

Comment: You have to keep a reference to the sprite and destroy it before creating it again. Check my code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible to implement. Here is how I would do it.

**1. Add a listener for `afterrender` event for `series`.**

```
listeners: {
                afterrender: function (p) {
                    this.doCustomDrawing();
                },
                scope: me
}
```

**2. Create a CompositeSprite**

```
doCustomDrawing: function () {
    var me = this, chart = me.chart;

    if (chart.rendered) {
        var series = chart.series.items[0];
        if (me.groupChain != null) {
            me.groupChain.destroy();
            me.groupChain = null;
        }

        me.groupChain = Ext.create('Ext.draw.CompositeSprite', {
            surface: chart.surface
        });

        // Draw hilight here
        Ext.each(series.items, function (item) {
            var storeItem = item.storeItem,
                pointX = item.point[0], 
                pointY = item.point[1];

            //TODO: Create your new line sprite using pointX and pointY
            // and add it to CompositeSprite me.groupChain  


        });

        me.groupChain.show(true);
    }
},
```

Comment: The solution works fine for me. The only problem is in case the container is resized the sprite is not cleared from the chart and remains in the same spot and will be redrawn as a new sprite in the right position. Do you know a way to circumvent this?

Comment: Make sure the old CompositeSprite is destroyed before creating a new one.

Comment: Yes after some try and error I noticed the different between my first solution and your answer. Now everything seems to work. thx

Answer (score 0):

There is no "built-in" way to go about this. You are probably running into some difficulties looking for it because "highlighting" a line chart currently means something totally different in the ExtJS API. It normally refers to making the line and markers bold when you hover the mouse over a data series.

However your idea sounds interesting, I might need use this in a project I have coming up.

I don't have the time to work out the exact code right now but this could be done by creating a rectangular [**sprite**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Sprite) and adding it to the chart's [**surface property**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.chart.Chart-property-surface).

You can do that even after the chart has been all rendered using the `Ext.draw.Surface.add` method as described [**here**](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.draw.Surface-method-add) in the docs.

You will have to come up with logic for determining width and positioning, if I remember the chart API properly, you should be able to extract x coordinates (horizontal location) of individual records by fishing around in the `items` property of the `Ext.chart.series.Line` object inside the chart.

The height of the highlight should be easy though - just read the height of the chart.